# Initials field in HTML form,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drupal

For a project i need a initial textfield which use the every first letter of a forname and bornnames. So basically the field needs to autoformat the input by user. If i fill in my initials MGJ it needs to be M.G.J. (after every letter he must put in the point).

Be aware;
The webform made with Webform module Drupal, so i only could use css or Javascript.

Are there some easy option for that?

Regards,
Martijn

Comment: Well you need to use js for that.

Comment: Yep i was pointing on that, do you have some tips or examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/ you can use this library to format your input the easy way.

**Or you can do it like this in JS**

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#initials');
input.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
  this.value = this.value.split('').join('.');
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="initials" />
```

Comment: Hi Amir, i have one more question on this, actually this works fine but, when people use ABC then he splits nicelly in A.B.C but is it possible to join a . after the C, cause if people who uses the from and typ in the dot then i get a output like: A..B..C.., Or maybe try to fetch the dots and only sets one dot in one split. Now i'm using something like this: if ($(".input-initialen")[0]){ $(".input-initialen").focusout(function() { this.value.split('').join('.'); }); }

Answer (score 2):

all you need to do is to split your string and then join with a dot.

```
    string.split('').join('.');
```

Comment: Is this also possible with a dutch postalcode ?? Like so: 1234 AB ?

Comment: when you split an string with '' actualy you are creating an array witch holds every letter as an element of your array like this. 'hello'.split('') will return ['h' , 'e' ,'l' , 'l' ,'o'] , so yes you can use it

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your explanation.

Comment: Your Welcome bro :)

Answer (score 1):

Late answer; I needed the same thing but wasn't happy with the current answers.

```js
document.getElementById('initialsOnly').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.code === 'Backspace') {
        this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
    } else {
        const newString = this.value.replace(/[\W\d]/g, '').split('').join('.').toUpperCase();
        this.value = newString + (newString.length > 0 ? '.' : '');
    }
});

document.getElementById('initialsOnly').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

```html
<input id="initialsOnly" type="text" />
```

Comment: I am not the TS, but this works very well Daan. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @mat. I have now added another event listener 'input' to automatically uppercase the inputted text as well. That way it looks a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Oke I allready found the solution my own; i used:

```
`$( document ).ready(function() {
        if ($(".input")[0]){
            $(".input").focusout(function() {
               var initials = this.value.replace(/\./g,'');
               this.value = initials.split('').join('.');
            });
        }
    });
    })( jQuery );`
```